# Changing values of moderator in plot_model from the sjPlot package

Tags: r, sjplot

I'm trying to create a plot of the interactive effect of two variables on an outcome variable in a linear regression model using `plot_model`. I have an interaction term in my model (BLK70*FP59), but when I use `type = "int"` I get "Error: No interaction term found in model."

I can get the plot I want using `type = "pred"`, but I want to change the values of the moderator term (FP59 below) in the interaction. How can I do this? See below example:

```
library(sjPlot)
model1 <- lm(HR70 ~ . - NAME - STATE_NAME,
       data = crimeExFilt)
model2 <- update(model1, ~ . - PO60 - PO70 -
              HC60 - HC70 - POL60 - POL70 -
              RD60 - RD70 - PS60 - PS70)
model3 <- update(model2, ~ . - GI69)
model4 <- update(model3, ~ . - GI59)
model5 <- update(model4, ~ . - MFIL59)
model6 <- update(model5, ~ . - FP69)
model7 <- update(model6, ~ . - FH60)
model8 <- update(model7, ~ . - DV60)
model9 <- update(model8, ~ . - UE60)
model10 <- update(model9, ~ . - DNL70)
model11 <- update(model10, ~ . - DNL60)
model12 <- update(model11, ~ . - BLK60)
model13 <- update(model12, ~ . - UE70)
model14 <- update(model13, ~ . + BLK70*FP59)
plot_model(model14, type = "pred", terms = c("BLK70", "FP59"))
```

In the `plot_model` documentation I can see the `mdrt.values` function, but that doesn't work with `type = "pred"`.

Also, how can I add more lines for differing values of FP59?

Edit: summary data is below from `dput(head(crimeExFilt, 20))`. I removed one variable (NAME) as its not relevant to the model and I was over the character count.

```
structure(list(STATE_NAME = structure(c(22L, 
46L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 11L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 33L, 
33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L), .Label = c("Alabama", "Arizona", 
"Arkansas", "California", "Colorado", "Connecticut", "Delaware", 
"District of Columbia", "Florida", "Georgia", "Idaho", "Illinois", 
"Indiana", "Iowa", "Kansas", "Kentucky", "Louisiana", "Maine", 
"Maryland", "Massachusetts", "Michigan", "Minnesota", "Mississippi", 
"Missouri", "Montana", "Nebraska", "Nevada", "New Hampshire", 
"New Jersey", "New Mexico", "New York", "North Carolina", "North Dakota", 
"Ohio", "Oklahoma", "Oregon", "Pennsylvania", "Rhode Island", 
"South Carolina", "South Dakota", "Tennessee", "Texas", "Utah", 
"Vermont", "Virginia", "Washington", "West Virginia", "Wisconsin", 
"Wyoming"), class = "factor"), SOUTH = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
HR60 = c(0, 0, 1.8638634161, 2.6123301985, 0, 0, 7.9763898859, 
1.0111734668, 11.529038766, 0, 0, 3.5740452832, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 2.9459419649, 0, 0, 0), HR70 = c(0, 0, 1.9151584794, 1.2886431876, 
0, 0, 5.5361789293, 1.6894745734, 9.2738569971, 5.7087400811, 
0, 3.8406882513, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8.1172125492), HC60 = c(0, 
0, 0.3333333333, 0.6666666667, 0, 0, 1, 0.3333333333, 1.3333333333, 
0, 0, 0.6666666667, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.3333333333, 0, 0, 0), HC70 = c(0, 
0, 0.3333333333, 0.3333333333, 0, 0, 1, 0.6666666667, 1, 
0.3333333333, 0, 0.6666666667, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.6666666667
), PO60 = c(4304L, 3889L, 17884L, 25520L, 6914L, 5809L, 12537L, 
32965L, 11565L, 7904L, 2624L, 18653L, 6458L, 5566L, 5886L, 
4698L, 11315L, 10641L, 5624L, 10064L), PO70 = c(3987L, 3655L, 
17405L, 25867L, 6025L, 5484L, 18063L, 39460L, 10783L, 5839L, 
2359L, 17358L, 5779L, 4564L, 4739L, 3828L, 9496L, 11549L, 
4645L, 8213L), RD60 = c(-0.17510549, -0.836868285, -0.537371617, 
-0.820169785, -0.93617014, -0.850319046, -1.40425979, -1.136291549, 
-0.314596351, -1.245690305, -0.972029373, -1.149784334, -0.591604056, 
-0.173043012, -0.048135919, -0.516882533, -0.550614009, 0.5252124234, 
-0.549590586, -0.005570979), RD70 = c(-0.1965356, -0.847855576, 
-0.225283145, -0.391126083, -0.45145694, -0.630179478, -1.542621404, 
-0.884559174, 0.2010717469, -0.636244755, -0.730313484, -0.769094521, 
-0.92383632, -0.582953792, -0.7195375, -0.893953808, -0.325512315, 
0.6192301296, 0.0670489427, -0.022077556), PS60 = c(-1.449946096, 
-1.707205577, -0.568146453, -0.554938608, -1.106438634, -1.20839428, 
-0.98204569, -0.346093185, -0.966681816, -1.116701907, -1.864842975, 
-0.592590111, -1.224457678, -1.248144375, -1.153201929, -1.247070389, 
-0.787183304, -0.625011616, -1.164168197, -0.842095066), 
PS70 = c(-1.462559387, -1.697719914, -0.591883439, -0.552016041, 
-1.181753555, -1.21941739, -0.697968638, -0.2317217, -1.002008852, 
-1.313787543, -1.878456577, -0.648495216, -1.274861798, -1.360590663, 
-1.283436317, -1.362946989, -0.907080663, -0.56253244, -1.274896982, 
-0.979372569), UE60 = c(7.9, 8.2, 10.1, 7.5, 10.6, 10.8, 
17.3, 13.8, 12.8, 5.5, 5.1, 6.3, 5.5, 5.1, 3.5, 4.1, 5.3, 
14.4, 6, 5.1), UE70 = c(9, 15.4, 9, 10.5, 13.4, 12.1, 10.3, 
9.8, 12.6, 3.6, 0.5, 4.3, 3, 4, 4.2, 6, 4.7, 11.9, 2.3, 3.3
), DV60 = c(1.858974359, 2.8632784538, 2.7114466184, 3.3720410898, 
3.0089878859, 2.5904203324, 3.4371395617, 2.5964850305, 3.8611039129, 
3.3008252063, 2.39912759, 2.4852844997, 1.7998244074, 1.1499760422, 
1.8885741265, 0.8891523414, 1.1185682327, 1.6148689823, 0.8713480267, 
0.8155230596), DV70 = c(2.6198083067, 3.6860068259, 2.9763779528, 
4.0903860236, 4.0106951872, 3.4893992933, 3.7966739881, 3.2997316702, 
3.5012809564, 4.0658276864, 3.1137724551, 2.514011209, 1.9626168224, 
1.529219006, 1.3264129181, 1.4035087719, 1.8281036835, 1.6844469399, 
1.4084507042, 0.8643617021), MA60 = c(28.8, 25.9, 29.6, 29.4, 
31.2, 27.6, 24.8, 30.1, 22.8, 25.9, 24.8, 24, 29.2, 29.2, 
29.7, 27.9, 28.3, 19.5, 29.5, 27), MA70 = c(30.5, 27.1, 31.8, 
31.1, 33.8, 30.3, 25.1, 28, 22.1, 29.4, 26.9, 24.2, 31.3, 
34.6, 33.4, 30.7, 32, 18.7, 33.2, 31.4), POL60 = c(8.3673001018, 
8.2659073342, 9.7916617374, 10.147217737, 8.8413036205, 8.667163718, 
9.4364395511, 10.403201672, 9.3557385747, 8.9751242394, 7.8724551501, 
9.83376227, 8.7730749513, 8.6244319421, 8.6803319288, 8.4548921652, 
9.3338845581, 9.2724697434, 8.6347984335, 9.2167199789), 
POL70 = c(8.2907943474, 8.2038513722, 9.7645128002, 10.160723304, 
8.7036727584, 8.6095900407, 9.8016209261, 10.58304278, 9.2857260989, 
8.6723148283, 7.7659930794, 9.7618087742, 8.6619859363, 8.425954711, 
8.463581422, 8.2500977526, 9.1586259363, 9.3543541321, 8.4435466512, 
9.0134735437), DNL60 = c(1.1887546181, 0.5687860169, 1.9752447537, 
1.5715669765, 1.5956485529, 1.5164622604, 1.2165748092, 1.8589771411, 
1.3614435882, 1.3995395879, 0.6007514432, 1.8520289834, 1.3382270761, 
1.4543123986, 1.6601412205, 1.6681752146, 1.9091227962, 2.4557338628, 
1.6849419785, 1.8955314222), DNL70 = c(1.1122488636, 0.5067300549, 
1.9480958166, 1.585072543, 1.4580176908, 1.4588885831, 1.5817561842, 
2.0388182491, 1.2914311125, 1.0967301767, 0.4942893725, 1.7800754875, 
1.2271380611, 1.2558351675, 1.4433907137, 1.463380802, 1.7338641745, 
2.5376182515, 1.4936901962, 1.692284987), MFIL59 = c(8.2201339572, 
8.5197898173, 8.403352375, 8.4799066066, 8.5083542427, 8.423102268, 
8.6094076754, 8.5926716526, 8.5504345252, 8.703340753, 8.6755635274, 
8.7339161749, 8.4228825119, 8.3390230057, 8.2456469009, 8.3219079682, 
8.3556149958, 8.1092249531, 8.4474142968, 8.2779202582), 
MFIL69 = c(8.7083092959, 9.0067543199, 8.8688354928, 8.969923492, 
8.8952185838, 8.946505026, 9.1810145426, 9.055672892, 8.942983666, 
9.0478214425, 9.0595174822, 9.0961633269, 9.0596337546, 8.8192218576, 
8.810012048, 8.9685235554, 8.9061223309, 8.7859982081, 8.8597894947, 
8.7677962556), FP59 = c(36.3, 22.5, 30.9, 25, 26.7, 27.2, 
16.8, 20, 28.7, 12.7, 16, 14.7, 27.9, 35.9, 37.8, 31.1, 25.7, 
45.2, 25.7, 35.2), FP69 = c(16.1, 11.6, 15.9, 12.9, 18.3, 
11.1, 5.9, 10.1, 23.4, 10.9, 8.1, 11.1, 8.2, 14.6, 14.6, 
10.7, 13.3, 28.9, 14.7, 14.5), BLK60 = c(0.4414498141, 0.0771406531, 
0.0782822635, 0.0979623824, 0.0289268152, 0, 0.0239291697, 
0.0819050508, 0.2075226978, 0.0126518219, 0, 0.1286656302, 
0.0929080211, 0.3413582465, 0, 0, 0.0353513036, 0.0939761301, 
0.0177809388, 0.029809221), BLK70 = c(0.4765487835, 2.2982216142, 
0.091927607, 0.2822128581, 0.0165975104, 0.0547045952, 0.0221447157, 
0.0760263558, 0.027821571, 0, 0, 0.4551215578, 0.0173040318, 
1.0297984224, 0.0211014982, 0, 0.0315922494, 0.05195255, 
0, 0), GI59 = c(0.2852352228, 0.2561578434, 0.2839986298, 
0.2585395475, 0.243262959, 0.2619385918, 0.2114246328, 0.2419263375, 
0.3168864307, 0.2399049248, 0.2863521291, 0.2596778551, 0.2699909989, 
0.3029912281, 0.2890553776, 0.2665788382, 0.2647430473, 0.3438081357, 
0.2705343299, 0.3234004078), GI69 = c(0.3723362149, 0.3606653751, 
0.3940828825, 0.3712181838, 0.3656140744, 0.3503513633, 0.2955509596, 
0.335356855, 0.3813660816, 0.3548185932, 0.3793765473, 0.3441587348, 
0.3427664904, 0.331764502, 0.341186868, 0.3280738529, 0.3836338256, 
0.3764732409, 0.417577773, 0.4092742788), FH60 = c(11.279620853, 
10.053475936, 9.2584369449, 9.0399002494, 8.2439299831, 7.1129707113, 
6.8727392305, 7.8634122881, 12.644595134, 9.4444444444, 9.2257001647, 
9.3560429305, 10.403530895, 11.547344111, 13.005390836, 9.8464317977, 
11.198501873, 14.565425024, 11.881918819, 12.213740458), 
FH70 = c(5.4, 2.6, 5.6, 8.1, 4.1, 6.8, 3.7, 6.4, 11.4, 8, 
5.6, 7.5, 6, 5.5, 2.5, 5.3, 6.8, 13.5, 8.4, 6.4)), row.names = c(NA, 
20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Please start your code examples with calls to `library(pkgname)` in order for us to know what packages you are using. `plot_model` can be found where? And in this case, the code that creates `model14`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas Apologies. Done.

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit the question with the output of `dput(crimeExFilt)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(crimeExFilt, 20))`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas Done again. See comments as I removed one variable to save space

Answer (score 1):

I'm posting an answer from the creator of the sjPlot package below. It includes the solution:

For marginal effects plots (type = "pred" and type = "eff"), plot_model() simply wraps the ggeffects package.

Please see these vignettes for different options for which values can be chosen:
https://strengejacke.github.io/ggeffects/articles/effectsatvalues.html

(and as introduction) https://strengejacke.github.io/ggeffects/articles/marginaleffects.html

or this vignette from sjPlot:
https://strengejacke.github.io/sjPlot/articles/plot_interactions.html

In your case, use e.g.

plot_model(model14, type = "pred", terms = c("BLK70", "FP59 [meansd]"))
plot_model(model14, type = "pred", terms = c("BLK70", "FP59 [quart]"))